# The partitive articles in negative sentences

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation, partitif

In this sentence “*de*” is an *article partitif*:

> Il ne boit pas de café au petit déjeuner.

Why? Is there any **préposition de négation** generally?

---

**Update:**

In negations “*ne … plus*”, “*ne … jamais*”, … like “*ne … pas*”, does the indefinite article become “*de*”?

What about the partitive articles in:

> 1. J'ai mis de l'essence dans la voiture.
> 2. C'est de l'or pur.

The respective negations are:

> 1. Je n'ai pas mis d'essence dans la voiture .
> 2. Ce n'est pas de l'or pur.

Why does “*de l'* ” become “*d'* ” in 1. and “*de l'* ” remains “*de l'* ” in 2.?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The partitive article *du/de la/de l'/des* becomes *de* after negations such as *ne ... pas*, *ne ... plus*, *ne ... jamais*, ..., or after adverbs that indicate a quantity: *un peu de café*, *beaucoup de café*, ...

See the article in the [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de), “de² (art. partitif)”, final remark.

Comment: :It means that the indefinite articles that becomes de after negation is partitive articles?préposition de négation does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

the rule is different after the verb être, we always use the definite article: c'est du bois, ce n'est pas du bois; c'est de l'argent, ce n'est pas de l'argent
De, du, de la, des, use the correct one: http://www.frenchspanishonline.com/magazine/de-du-de-la-des-in-french/

Answer (score 0):

In the second sentence we negate the verb "être". This is the only exception to the general rule. 
Actually, the indefinite article remains after a few status verbs such as "être", "paraître" and "devenir".

- Elle n'a pas paru une folle - plutôt une femme gâtée.

Comment: Do you have some references?