# Why are the indefinite articles replaced with de/d' in negative sentences (most of the time)?

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, articles, histoire

Basically, I am wondering if there is any historical, grammatical, or other possible reason/motivation as to why the indefinite articles are replaced with de/d' in negative sentences (most of the time). Likewise, are there similar reasons for why clauses featuring the verb être are exempt from this rule?

Hope my question is clear!

Comment: Some examples perhaps?

Comment: @MathieuBouville There are already numerous examples of *de* in negative sentences on FL, [e.g. here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1744/358), so there's no need to add more. A link to that question, or another will probably be enough, the question is clear as it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a matter of avoiding ambiguity: what is negated? (Which may not explain all cases.)

> Je n'ai pas de mari = I am not married
>
> Je n'ai pas des maris = I am not polygamous (negation of the plural)