# where are 'le' and 'la' needed and where are they omitted?

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

I'm a beginner in French and I am confused with these two sentences:

1. j'ai **de la** bière (I have some beer)
2. je n'ai pas **de** bière (I have no beer)

I've heard that 'de' can be translated as 'some' or 'any'. So why these two are different? Why there is no 'la' in the second sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "**la**" in the second sentence because it has a negative form. It will always be the same:

"J'ai **du** café / Je n'ai pas **de** café"

please notice that "**du**" is the contraction of "**de le**", and therefore, "*de le*" cannot be used in French, except when the following noun begins with a vowel, so "**du**" becomes " **de l'**" because in French we must avoid as much as possible that a syllable ending with a vowel be followed by another vowel, so we can't say "du argent" then we go back to "de le", but erase the "e" to avoid that double wowel, like in this example :

"J'ai **de l**'argent / Je n'ai pas  **d**'argent"

"J'ai **de la** chance / je n'ai pas **de** chance "

Comment: What was wrong with [the answer to that question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1744/358)?

Comment: I just didn't see there had been an answer, but I guess it surely was a good answer.